# Project mesh on surface (or clip face with rotation)

Tags: mesh, transforms, add-on

Is there a way I can "project" a mesh on another mesh's surface?
I know clipping, but it doesn't align the faces that are touching and doing it manually can be very time consuming.

Is there an integrated function or addon to do such a thing?
In case not, can somebody please point me in the right direction to write a py script? (I regularly code in python, just never wrote anything for blender)

Here's a real-world example to explain things graphically:

I want to go from **this**

[image]

to **this**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To place cube onto the surface of torus in this case, you should:

1. Enable `Snap during transform` tool with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Turn on Face snapping mode, along with `Align rotation with the snapping target`. Switch snapping part onto the target to `Median`:

   [image]
2. Grab your object (cube) to the desired place. Switch `Transformation orietnation` to `Normal` (with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>). Turn off snapping and grab your cube along normals so it moves out of the base mesh surface (in my case it was `Z` axis):

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mr Zak! :D

Eventually solved by clicking the *two* buttons near the snap tool with face-snapping selected. When I move an object it automatically gets projected on the surrounding mesh's surface :)

Here's a small screenshot:

[image]